# If we have state for the value attribute in the input box, how can we set the previous value when we hit escape in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an input box where I need to set previous value in the input box when hit Esc key.
I have tried with ref but it did not work for me. Here prevValue means
suppose I have enter 56 and enter ,now I changed to 99  and when press escape it should come as 56

Here is the sandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-platform-rruvt?file=/src/App.js

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App({initialvalue}) {
  const [val, setValue] = useState(initialvalue);
  const onEscapeHandler = () => {
    //here need to set the previous value
    setValue(val);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        className="form"
        placeholder="Type something here"
        value={val}
        onEscape={onEscapeHandler}
        
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: So it sounds more like you want an "undo" function. How much history do you want to save? If user enters twice do you keep only the last value entered (to undo)? Can you provide a bit more context around desired behavior?

Comment: suppose user enter 77 and again change it to 77, it should be 77 and  the user enter 99 then hit esc it should be 77, we need to  have 2 values not the total history right?

Comment: I see. I updated my answer below with what I believe meets your updated requirements.

Comment: So has an answer here helped resolve your question/issue?

Answer (score 0):

do not complicated

use a custom attribute

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [val, setValue] = useState("");

 const onEscapeHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      const prev = document.getElementById("input-id")
      setValue(prev.getAttribute("data-prev"));
    }
  };

const onBlurInput = e =>{
 const val = e.target.value;
 
 const input = document.getElementById("input-id");
 input.setAttribute("data-prev", val);
}

const onChangeInput = e => {
setValue(e.currentTarget.value);
}

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        id="input-id"
        className="form"
        data-prev="initial-value"
        placeholder="Type something here"
        value={val}
        onKeyDown={onEscapeHandler}
        onBlur={onBlurInput}
        onChange={onChangeInput}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Querying the DOM is a bit anti-pattern in React, better to use an attached ref to access the DOMNodes. Also, why leak previous value out to DOM?

Answer (score -1):

Keep a reference to the previous value in your state.

In the example below, I use an array (stack), to keep previous values and pop them when user presses escape key by listening to `onKeyDown` event.

```js
function App() {
  const [val, setValue] = React.useState({ prev: [], curr: "" });
  const onEscapeHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) { // User Pressed Escape
      // Escape Handler
      setValue({ ...val, curr: val.prev.pop() });
      console.log("You pressed the escape key!", val);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        className="form"
        placeholder="Type something here"
        value={val.curr}
        onKeyDown={onEscapeHandler}
        onChange={(e) =>
          setValue({
            prev: [...val.prev, val.curr], // Keep ref to previous value
            curr: e.target.value // Update current value
          })
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

This is a very trivial example.

If you need to maintain a history of input, better option is to use a state management library like Redux or Zustand.

Comment: I need to set the previously entered value, like suppose  pevious  value is 78 and  current entered value is 99 and we press escape it should set to  78

Comment: You want to undo for a complete input of string and not individual characters?

Comment: I agree, but this seems to happen sometimes. Here it's not really clear why the downvote since OP's question so far was a bit ambiguous and I feel we've attempted to meet both the original question and the update.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `usePrevious` custom hook to hold the previous value and use the `onKeyDown` event handler on the input (*`onEscape` isn't a valid event handler*).

```
const usePrevious = value => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
};

export default function App() {
  const [val, setValue] = useState("");

  const previous = usePrevious(val); // <-- cache previous value

  const onEscapeHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      setValue(previous); // <-- restore previous value
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        className="form"
        placeholder="Type something here"
        value={val}
        onKeyDown={onEscapeHandler}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit if-we-have-state-for-the-value-attribute-in-the-input-box-how-can-we-set-the-pr]

#### Update

Since you want more of an undo, a suggestion then is to use a ref to store a previous "committed" value, and to use a form to "commit" the current input value to be the previous value. Difference is instead of caching each incremental input change, cache a "saved" result when entering.

```
const CustomInput = ({ initialValue = "" }) => {
  const [val, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  const previous = useRef();

  const setValueHandler = (e) => setValue(e.target.value);

  const saveValueHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    previous.current = val;
  };

  const onEscapeHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      previous.current && setValue(previous.current);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={saveValueHandler}>
      <input
        className="form"
        placeholder="Type something here"
        value={val}
        onKeyDown={onEscapeHandler}
        onChange={setValueHandler}
      />
    </form>
  );
};
```

Usage:

```
<CustomInput />
<CustomInput initialValue={42} />
```

[image: Edit if-we-have-state-for-the-value-attribute-in-the-input-box-how-can-we-set-the-pr (forked)]

Comment: This looks fine,  but I don't have onSubmit functioanlity, I  need to implement onEscape in the input box with the previous value.

Comment: And I already have state with initialvalue as props and need to set inside the onEscape handler and I am doing that but the value is  not updated with previous value

Comment: @vamsikrishna Sorry, I don't quite follow. `onEscape` isn't an event that can be handled, it doesn't exist, so you will *need to **implement*** and *add this ***new*** behavior* via existing event handlers and additional logic. Is the code in your snippet not an accurate representation of the *actual* code you have an issue with or that you're trying to get working? It feels like you keep moving the goal post.

Comment: @vamsikrishna Passing a prop or setting an initial state value is a bit unrelated to the question/issue of undoing the last "uncommitted" change, but I updated my proposed solution to include an initial value passed as a prop.